# How to run selenium scripts using safari driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to launch a URL and want to find some element in that page. While trying to execute with safari, URL gets launched but find element or any other action using webdriver instance throws an exception as null pointer. The same code works fine for chrome driver. I'm trying this in Windows machine

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Safari Technology Preview. Take help from [WebDriver Support in Safari 10](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/)

Try using the below code:

```
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setUseCleanSession(true);
options.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
currentDriver = new SafariDriver(options);
```